# How to call multiple micro services in saga work flow

Tags: masstransit

I am trying to call multiple micro services in one saga workflow class. Below is my code which is not working please let me know how to fix it. Really appreciate your help.

I am able to make the notification service work if i publish the message from payment consumer method. but i want to call my notification dependency class from saga workflow.

```
public class PaymentSaga : MassTransitStateMachine<PaymentSagaStatus>,IPayment
{
        public PaymentSaga()
        {
            InstanceState(s => s.CurrentState);

            Event(() => PaymentCollectCommand, x =>
            x.CorrelateBy(pay => pay.StudentId.ToString(),
                context => context.Message.StudentId.ToString())
            .SelectId(context => Guid.NewGuid()));

            // Payment
            Event(() => PaymentCollectedEvent, x => x.CorrelateById(context =>
                context.Message.CorrelationId));

            // Notification
            Event(() => NotificationEvent, x => x.CorrelateById(context =>
                context.Message.CorrelationId));

            Initially(
                When(PaymentCollectCommand)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    // Will be done by auto mapper                    
                    context.Instance.ReceivedPaymentDate = DateTime.Now;
                    context.Instance.StudentId = context.Data.StudentId;
                    context.Instance.CourseName = context.Data.CourseName;
                    context.Instance.Amount = context.Data.Amount;
                    context.Instance.TransactionDate = context.Data.TransactionDate;
                })
                // Send to payment Service
                .ThenAsync(
                    context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(
                        $"Student payment received. Id:{context.Instance.CorrelationId}"))
                    .TransitionTo(ReceivePayment)
                    .Publish(context => new PaymentReceivedEvent(context.Instance))                                
                );

            During(ReceivePayment,
                When(PaymentCollectedEvent)
                    .Then(context => context.Instance.ReceivedPaymentDate = DateTime.Now)
                    .ThenAsync(
                        context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(
                            $"Student payment processed. Id: {context.Instance.CorrelationId}")),

                When(NotificationEvent)
                    .Then(context =>
                    {
                        // Will be done by auto mapper                    
                        context.Instance.ReceivedPaymentDate = DateTime.Now;
                        context.Instance.Message = context.Data.Message;
                    })
                    .ThenAsync(context => Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(
                        $"Notification send. Id: {context.Instance.CorrelationId}"))
                    .TransitionTo(NotificationReceived)
                    .Publish(context => new NotificationReceivedEvent(context.Instance))
                    .Finalize());            
            SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
        }

        public State ReceivePayment { get; private set; }
        public State NotificationReceived { get; private set; }

        public Event<IPayment> PaymentCollectCommand { get; private set; }
        public Event<IPaymentReceivedEvent> PaymentCollectedEvent { get; private set; }
        public Event<INotification> NotificationEvent { get; private set; }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentReceivedEvent : IPaymentReceivedEvent
{
    private readonly PaymentSagaStatus _instance;

    public PaymentReceivedEvent(PaymentSagaStatus instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public Guid CorrelationId => _instance.CorrelationId;
    public int StudentId => _instance.StudentId;
    public string CourseName => _instance.CourseName;
    public DateTime TransactionDate => _instance.TransactionDate;
    public double Amount => _instance.Amount;
}

public class NotificationReceivedEvent : INotification
{
    private readonly PaymentSagaStatus _instance;

    public NotificationReceivedEvent(PaymentSagaStatus instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
    }

    public Guid CorrelationId => _instance.CorrelationId;

    public string Message => $"{_instance.StudentId} is being enrolled in {_instance.CourseName}. Fee paid: £{_instance.Amount}";
}
```

Comment: What exactly is _not working_ here?

Comment: basically i want to know how to call multiple micro services in Saga workflow. In the above workflow i am not able to fire the NotificationEvent after PaymentCollectedEvent. Any idea how to call a hand full of micro services in sequence using Sagas.

Comment: This unit test shows two services called in order: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.AutomatonymousIntegration.Tests/Request_Specs.cs#L340